# hoe to set Custom Path for Python Django logger in basicConfig

Tags: django, python-3.x, logging

How to save the python logs in a custom path other than a Base directory.

my code is like this

```
logging.basicConfig(filename=  '../applicationz.log', level=logging.ERROR,
                format='%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(name)s %(message)s')
```

logger=logging.getLogger(**name**)

it always store the log in Base directory.

I am using Ubuntu 16 - and in production its a AWS server with Apache.

Answer (score 0):

You are providing file as '../applicationz.log'. That's why it is storing in the base directory. Add the folder path with the filename to store the logs in any particular folder. You can also use 'os.path.join()' to specify the path.

```
filename = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'logs/applicationz.log')
```

Then logs will be stored in the logs folder.

Comment: i tried. No use. I need to store completly in a new directory for eg Desktop

Comment: you will also have to provide writing permissions to your SERVER_USER to that directory. In case of Apache, that is APACHE_USER

Comment: Permission was there. I think the line logger=logging.getLogger(__name__)    has default of base directoty path

Comment: NO. that's not correct. I have been using the same thing in my project and it is working fine. However, would you please try some folder inside your base directory rather than desktop?

Comment: Inside BaseDire Its working fine. I need something like "-/opt/python/log/app.out.filename.log"